# Using my play framework model classes in an other java application

Tags: java, playframework, model, frameworks

i want to create a project, which contains a play 2 Java application and a plain Java Application for the administrator.
In the play app i'm using the ebean orm (play.db.ebean) and i would like to use the same model classes in my Java app. Is it possible?
When I want to use them, i get this Exception:
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application"

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Could you provide us with some code showing how you're trying to use the models outside of Play?

Comment: Thank you. I just tested if it's possible. I created a java project and imported the classes i need. Even if i want to create a new object of a model class (like User u=new User () ) i get an exception that there is no play application running.

Comment: If your model classes aren't just some [POJOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and they contain some Play specific logic OR you're trying to use methods that involve the use of Ebean, I don't think that it will work outside the context of the Play application. Could you at least post the full stack trace at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it in your question? its diffucult to figure out whats wrong without more info

Answer (score 1):

In order to use ebean outside of play, you have to start the ebean agent

```
AgentLoader.loadAgentFromClasspath("avaje-ebeanorm-agent","debug=1;packages=org.yourclass.data.models.**")
```

and connect to a server as configured programmatically  or through an ebean.properties file in much the same way you do in the play framework application.conf file.

This page gives more details and should get you there.

[Ebean ORM Quick start](http://ebean-orm.github.io/quickstart)